# How to show a many-to-many field with "list_display" in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Price')
```

I have that code. Unfortunately, the error comes in admin.py with the `ManyToManyField`

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount']
    list_display = ('product', 'vendor')
```

The error says:

> 'PurchaseOrderAdmin.list_display[0]', 'product' is a ManyToManyField
> which is not supported.

However, it compiles when I take `'product'` out of `list_display`. So how can I display `'product'` in `list_display` without giving it errors?

**edit**: Maybe a better question would be how do you display a `ManyToManyField` in `list_display`?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You may not be able to do it directly. [From the documentation of `list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

> ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail
>   executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you
>   want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add
>   that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom
>   methods in list_display.)

You can do something like this:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount']
    list_display = ('get_products', 'vendor')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in obj.product.all()])
```

OR define a model method, and use that

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Price')

    def get_products(self):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])
```

and in the admin `list_display`

```
list_display = ('get_products', 'vendor')
```

Comment: This looks like a really good solution. Thank you. Although, I'm now getting an error saying "null value in column "product_id" violates not-null constraint
" Any idea what this means?

Comment: That could be a data issue. Check the values in the database

Comment: Since this brings down the database to its knees, how would you do it with select_related() or prefetch_related() to improve performance?

Comment: Just in case the optimisation question is still interesting, I just had the same problem and found out that you could simply implement an optimised `get_queryset()` method for your `ModelAdmin`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354099/override-default-queryset-in-django-admin/12354293#12354293

Comment: That's an interesting link @goetz but I'm not sure we can all follow on how that relates to improving performance

Comment: Actually, What about setting the `get_products` as a property and then using `@cached_property`?

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste Good idea, maybe `cached_property` would help. But I think it would probably not. When you use an optimised `get_queryset`, you could for example annotate/pre-process the data there, like doing the concatenation of  products in SQL instead of in Django, and store your custom data in your queryset. Then you would only need to execute that logic once in SQL and not for every row when the property is accessed.

Comment: Good point. I should look into doing my own optimized `get_queryset`, I just haven't got around to reading the full docs (nor found a simple enough example of what I should be doing)

Answer (score 30):

This way you can do it, kindly checkout the following snippet:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    """ Base category model class """

    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    parent      = models.ManyToManyField('self', default=None, blank=True)
    when        = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)

    def get_parents(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.parent.all()])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.title)
```

And in your admin.py module call method as follows:

```
class categories(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display    = ('title', 'get_parents', 'when')
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to save extra queries, you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in the `get_queryset` method like below:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount']
    list_display = ('get_products', 'vendor')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.prefetch_related('product')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return ",".join([p.products for p in obj.product.all()])
```

According to the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), In this way, there would be just one extra query needed to fetch related `Product` items of all `PurchaseOrder` instances instead of needing one query per each `PurchaseOrder` instance.

Answer (score 4):

For example, there are `Category` and `Product` models which have **many-to-many relationship** as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

Then, there are `Category` and `Product` admins as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    ordering = ('id',)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price')
    ordering = ('id',)
```

Then, `Category` admin has 5 objects as shown below:

[image]

And, `Product` admin has 6 objects as shown below:

[image]

Now, define `get_products` and `get_categories()` with [@admin.display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator), then set them to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in `Category` and `Product` admins respectively as shown below. *`description` argument in `@admin.display()` can rename the columns in Django Admin from `GET PRODUCTS` and `GET CATEGORIES` to `PRODUCTS` and `CATEGORIES` respectively:

```py
# "admin.py"

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'get_products')
    ordering = ('id',)            # Here

    # Here
    @admin.display(description='products')
    def get_products(self, obj):
        return [product.name for product in obj.product_set.all()]

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):      # Here  
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'get_categories')
    ordering = ('id',)
    
    # Here
    @admin.display(description='categories')
    def get_categories(self, obj):
        return [category.name for category in obj.categories.all()]
```

Then, `PRODUCTS` column is displayed in `Category` admin as shown below:

[image]

Then, `CATEGORIES` column is displayed in `Product` admin as shown below:

[image]

Also, you can display `PRODUCTS` and `CATEGORIES` columns by defining `get_products()` and `get_categories()` with `@admin.display()` in `Category` and `Product` models respectively as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # Here
    @admin.display(description='products')
    def get_products(self):
        return [product.name for product in self.product_set.all()]

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

    # Here
    @admin.display(description='categories')
    def get_categories(self):
        return [category.name for category in self.categories.all()]
```

Then, set them to `list_display` in `Category` and `Product` admins respectively as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

...

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'get_products')
    ordering = ('id',)            # Here

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):      # Here
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'get_categories')
    ordering = ('id',)
```