# List_display for ManytoMany fields in Admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 apps: `Visitors` and `Meetings`, linked via a `ManytoMany` field:

visitors/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from meetings.models import Meeting

class Visitor(models.Model):

    visitor_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    visitor_meetings = models.ManyToManyField(Meeting)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.visitor_name
```

meetings/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from team.models import Team

class Meeting(models.Model):
    team_member = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    meeting_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.meeting_name
```

I know the correct way to get a `list_display` for meetings in the `Visitors` admin panel is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108586/2429989.

However, how can I show a `list_display` for visitors at each meeting in the **`Meetings`** admin panel? I have tried:

meetings/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Meeting
from visitors.models import Visitor

class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'team_member', 'show_visitors' ]

    def show_visitors(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([a.visitor_name for a in obj.visitor.all()])

admin.site.register(Meeting, MeetingAdmin)
```

This results in `'Meeting' object has no attribute 'visitor'`, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try changing `obj.visitor.all()` for `obj.visitor_set.all()`

Comment: @CésarBustíos thanks! This worked, but can you explain why please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default reverse lookup relation it's always [`obj.tablename_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). In your case you need to use `obj.visitor_set.all()`

```
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'team_member', 'show_visitors' ]

    def show_visitors(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([a.visitor_name for a in obj.visitor_set.all()])
```

However, you can customize the name of the reverse lookup by defining the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    visitor_name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    visitor_meetings = models.ManyToManyField(Meeting, related_name='visitors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.visitor_name
```

All `Meeting` objects will now have access to `visitors`. Use it like:

```
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'team_member', 'show_visitors' ]

    def show_visitors(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([a.visitor_name for a in obj.visitors.all()])
```