# Django admin panel list_display show none even after fetching data

Tags: python, django

I am displaying data in Django admin panel for many to many relationship tables. I got None instead of a list of names.

I am using:

- Python: 3.6
- Django: 2.2

[List_display for ManytoMany fields in Admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475104/list-display-for-manytomany-fields-in-admin-panel)

I had also already asked a related question on this topic. That being said I changed my model since then (I also got not answers).

models:

```
class Assessment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 

class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

class Seminar(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        assessment = models.ManyToManyField(Assessment,blank=True)
        participant =       models.ManyToManyField(Participant,blank=True,through='SeminarParticipant',through_fields=('seminar','participant'))

class SeminarParticipant(models.Model): 
    seminar = models.ForeignKey(Seminar,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0),])
    is_survey_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

admin:

```
@admin.register(Seminar)
class SeminarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('topic''assessment')  

    def assessment(self,obj):
        return "\n".join([item for item in obj.assessment.all()])
```

I was expecting name of assessment in list_display of seminar admin but got `assessments.Assessment.None` in list_display of admin panel.

Snapshot of output:
[image: snap shot of output]

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assessment` is the name of the field, which will be found before your method. Call the method something else and use that name in `list_display`.

```
class SeminarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('topic', 'assessment_list')  

    def assessment_list(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([item for item in obj.assessment.all()])
```

(Although note, `assessment` is an odd name for a field that contains *many* assessments; you should think about renaming the field itself.)

Comment: actually item.name for item in obj.assessment.all() work for me. And thanks for the clarification towards naming things in django.
Thanks alot! @Daniel Roseman