# how to make many-to-many in list display django more efficient

Tags: django-admin

I'm using django 1.8.
I'm displaying a many-to-many field in django admin like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108521/many-to-many-in-list-display-django).

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Price')


class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products

class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount']
    list_display = ('get_products', 'vendor')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in obj.product.all()])
```

The problem is that if I display 100 rows per page, it does 100 queries.
For foreign keys, there is a magical **list_select_related** but you cannot put many-to-many fields in there.
How can I avoid duplicate queries?

--- update:

I've tried:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PurchaseOrderAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.prefetch_related('products')
```

It is still doing duplicate queries per row.

Comment: Try using prefetch_related. It does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryShilyaev Unfortunately it is still doing duplicate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also need to do a `select_related('product')` as part of the `get_queryset`?

Hard to really say since I don't see the model relation

Comment: prefetch_related for M2M. I've added the model in the question as well.