# ManyToManyField shows all the instances instead of related

Tags: python, django

My models:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2,default=0.00)

class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
```

When I add `CartItem` instance to a cart and then look at the `Cart` instance in admin dashboard, I see all the `CartItem` instances instead of the one's I added to the cart. How do I fix it?
That's what I mean:

[image]
**But I only added Dell and Canon instances.**

Comment: please post the admin classes.

Comment: I use the default one's

Comment: Yes this is what it is supposed to be. Its the edit page, you will see all the choices to select for the field and preselected choices which already exist, which are highlighted.

Comment: I see. Would you suggest a way to show the selected choices in admin dashboard?

Comment: In the list view? If yes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108586/5312750).

Comment: What would be the point of only showing the selected ones? Then you wouldn't be able to select any others.

Answer (score 0):

The selected items are displayed right as highlighted.
If you want selected items display in another input, use FilteredSelectMultiple widget as:

forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(None, widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Items", False, attrs={'rows':'10'}))

Comment: you  need to replace 'None' use your model.