# How to make a one to many relationship in Django/Mysql?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am trying to understand how to make a one to many relationship in Django/Mysql?

[image]

**Here is models.py (code below)**

```
class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.OneToOneField(Estados, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    especie = models.ForeignKey('Listaflor', models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie'),)


class Listaflor(models.Model):
    especie = models.OneToOneField(Flora2Estado, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    familia = models.ForeignKey(Familia, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='especie', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because of name conflict.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'listaflor'

class Estados(models.Model):
    estado_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estado_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estados
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is a Many2Many relation between Listaflor and Estados through another class called Flora2Estado. [Django M2M relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class Estados(models.Model):
    estado_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estado_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estados'


class Listaflor(models.Model):
    especie_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='especie', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    estados = models.ManyToManyField(Estados, through='Flora2Estado')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'listaflor'


class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estados, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    especie = models.ForeignKey(Listaflor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie'),)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your reply.
I've used the code you suggested, but i got an error:

ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.floAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[6]' must not be a ManyToManyField.

Do you how can I fix it?

Once again, thanks a lot

Comment: This is happening because in your admin.py you are trying to use list_display with the M2M field and is not allowed. This other post can help you to fix it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108521/many-to-many-in-list-display-django)

Comment: thank you so much for your help! It worked! You saved me!