# How to fix manytomany field in django

Tags: python, django

[How to make a one to many relationship in Django/Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900937/how-to-make-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django-mysql)

I have an identical situation to this post, yet, my django returns errors on the admin page:

> get() returned more than one order2pizza-- it returned 5!

> order2pizza with that pizza already exists.

My mysql database have composite keys on a tertiary table to order and pizza to link multiple pizzas to an order.

models.py:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class Pizza(models.Model):
    Pizza= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Pizza_name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class order2pizza(models.Model):
    order = models.ManyToManyField(Orders, models.DO_NOTHING, )
    pizza_id= models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('order ', 'pizza_id'),)
```

Comment: Why do you want to create another model for relating pizza and order? You can directly use the `ManyToManyField` in your `Pizza` model. like this : `orders = models.ManyToManyField(Orders, blank=True, null=True)`.

Comment: @Ajay Interesting!, but i need to use the actual relations already estabilished by the db, how can i migrate this on mysql, is there a way that you can guide me to?

Comment: Where did you see the `get() returned more than one order2pizza` error?

Comment: @Jaap I got it after clicking on an item inside order2pizza admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A many-to-many relation can be expressed in two ways. First, you can manually specify a "join" model, like this:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    Pizza_name= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Order2Pizza(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, models.CASCADE)
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['order ', 'pizza']
```

This is useful if you want to put extra fields on the Order2Pizza model. A field named `quantity` would be very useful in your example.

The second option is to use a `ManyToManyField`. This will automatically create the join model for you:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    pizzas = models.ManyToManyField('Pizza', related_name='orders')

class Pizza(models.Model):
    Pizza_name= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

In your original question you put the `ManyToManyField` on the `Order2Pizza` model, which is nonsensical.

However, the source of your bug is probably your manual inclusion of several `*_id` fields. Don't do that. They will always be created automatically by Django and you should never have to specify them manually. Instead, try the two options above and see how they work.