# Django many to many field, but display just the highest value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to know how I can display the highest ranking from the model education in the staff. The user would be able to select all of their educations, but for me it's irrelevant to know if the the user selected "high school" when he/she also has a master's degree.

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    education = models.ManyToManyField('Education', verbose_name = 'Education')
```

```
class Education(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I gave every type of education a ranking.

So in the Admin, the only thing I want returned would be the highest eduacation by a member of the staff - how do I write this function?

```
class StaffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('rank', )
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108521/many-to-many-in-list-display-django. You can't access it directly, but can write custom method to display whatever you want. Also see Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: do you know what the code would look like? and where would I put it. thank you btw!!!

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this code is not tested, it's just to show you the of the possible solutions.

You can use `@admin.display` decorator (see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)).
You also should modify `get_queryset()` method so you retrieve ranks for all Staff objects and won't hit a database for every row.
So your code will look something like that

```
class StaffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('highest_rank', )
    
    @admin.display(description="Employee's highest education rank")
    def highest_rank(obj):
       top_rank = obj.Education.order_by("-rank").first()  # may return None
       return rank.name

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(StaffAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        # get related model so we don't hit database for every Staff row
        return qs.prefetch_related("Education")
```