# How to display value on fields based on queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i have a case like this :
**Models**

```
class Car(models.Model):
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     is_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Rental(models.Model):
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

My question is, how to display Car on Rental models with is_available = True. On django admin ?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many in list display django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108521/many-to-many-in-list-display-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get_queryset` method of the django admin class.

Generic Syntax for that->

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

In your case this would be -:

```
class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self,request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(car__is_available=True)
```

You can Refer to the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#:%7E:text=class%20MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20get_queryset(self%2C%20request)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20qs%20%3D%20super().get_queryset(request)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20request.user.is_superuser%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20qs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20qs.filter(author%3Drequest.user))

For Inline your code should be -:

```
class CarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model=Rental.car.through
    #model=Car
    def get_queryset(self,request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_available=True)

class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[CarInline]
```

Comment: Okey, that's work. I miss explain the question. So how about when i click add new Rental, and list of car will display car that is_available = True ?

Comment: You can Use Inline model admin and add get_queryset model to that class. I am editing my anwer, refer to that

Comment: I have edited the anwser,You can try it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can try django  [inline model admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)