# Customize list_filter results

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to limit the results that the django "list_filter" displays in Django admin.

According to my models below, I only want it to show categories (in the filter) that are in the Class Category and contain the tier integer "1".

Is this possible?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    tier = models.IntegerField(blank=false)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    link = models.URLField("Link", max_length=900)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

In admin, I've got:

```
list_filter = ('category')
```

I believe I'd need to incorporate this some how?

```
category=Category.objects.get(tier__iexact='1')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354099/override-default-queryset-in-django-admin

Comment: I dont want to hide it globally- only for the list_filter in the "admin" section. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CategoryListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Category')
    parameter_name = 'category'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        categories = Category.objects.filter(tier=1)
        for obj in categories:
            yield (str(obj.pk), smart_text(obj))

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(category__id=self.value())


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (CategoryListFilter,)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: Sorry- this doesn't work. It shows the right filtering criteria, but does NOT show the right content when filtered. It only returns one (random) single object from my model.

Comment: Ah, I just had to change the queryset. `return queryset.filter(category__id=self.value())` . Voila- it worked. I updated your answer.

Comment: Yep. Totally missed that. Thanks!