# Exclude duplicates from django admin page

Tags: python, django, admin

My question is the following: can you exclude objects that are duplicated from being displayed on the admin page without DB modification, and if yes, how?

Thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354099/override-default-queryset-in-django-admin) will teach you a lot about ModelAdmin queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `queryset` inside your Admin model

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    # update your query somehow
    return qs.distinct()
```